# Where is the StructureChangedNotification in Team Foundation Server 2013?

Tags: tfs

I try to create a EventHandler for Team Foundation 2013.
I want to get a notification when a new iteration or sprint is created.
For this i think i need the StructureChangedNotification!
In Team Foundation Server 2010 it was located in Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.dll.
But in TFS 2013 it has gone! Where is it? Or do you have another approach how to get events if a new iteration/sprint has been created, deleted or modified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Integration.Server.StructureChangedNotification, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.Core

Comment: Thank you so much! It's not documented anywhere... isn't it? Even here  its not:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.server.core.aspx

Comment: Just as a hint for the next time: Get Jetbrains DotPeek and add all assemblies of the directory "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 12.0\Application Tier\Web Services\bin" to the assembly explorer. Than use "Navigate --> Go To Everything" and type in the type you want to find.